# How to repair database corruption from backup?

Tags: sql-server, corruption

I am learning about dbcc checkdb and that it detects corruption.

Suppose checkdb results show corruption in db.

What is the way to fix the corruption suppose I have the db backup?

Comment: It'll help you to solve you problem https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-perform-a-page-level-restore-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't repair it using the backup. You restore from a prior backup which is clean. I.e., the basics are, after detecting the corruption:

1. Perform the last log backup if possible, make sure that no-one is doing further modifications in the database.
2. Restore from a *clean* full backup
3. Restore from a subsequent *clean* diff backup, if you have such.
4. Restore an unbroken chain of log backups, if you have such, including the very last one you took in step 1.

You hopefully now have a clean database. Of course there are a lot of aspects around this (doing root cause analysis, etc). Brent Ozar has written a great blog post on this that I highly recommend: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/

Comment: Isn't it possible to restore an older backup (without corruption), then use a command to pick up the page data and apply it to the production db to heal the corruption?

Comment: Sure. Just be aware that you now are responsible for that the database has tables with data from different point in time.

Comment: Another way is to restore the full backup from before the corruption reported and then apply subsequent differential and log backups

Comment: That is exactly what I proposed in my answer. Note that the diff backup (as well as the full backup) need to be from before the corruption occured.

Comment: Ok so you mean only log backups can be from during/after the corruption? Why is that? And does this mean a db in simple recovery mode cannot have its corruption corrected because it wont have any TLogs?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that a diff backup contains the pages from the database, files. Restore such after the corruption occurred and you might just now have restored those corrupt pages. A log backup contains log records, not an image of the data pages. (Unless you are in bulk logged recovery models and have done a minimally logged operation, where a log backup can contain pages as well.)